# why should you clone react state before changing it or when working on it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been told that whenever I am working with react state or changing it, I should make a clone or copy of it.

```
const cloneState = [...this.state]
cloneState.name = 'hardik'
```

But I am not sure why people recommend it, Why can't i directy change state?

why shouldn't I just do it using it

```
this.setState({name: 'hardik'})
```

Comment: In your example, you can definitely use `this.setState({name: 'hardik'})` as [React class components' `setState` do a shallow merge automatically.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

Answer (score 2):

React determines whether or not to re-render a component based on whether the state has changed.

It determines whether or not the state has changed by testing its referential equality.

This means that it'll check if `this.state === this.state`

If you mutate a piece of state, say by doing: `cloneState.name = "hardik"` the states will be referentially equal since it was a mutation.

When you "clone" the state by creating a new object `[...this.state] === this.state` is false which triggers a re-render.

Comment: Can you please explain this line `referentially equal since it was a mutation`

Comment: Sorry! Referential equality is checking whether or not `objectA` is the same object as `objectB`. So if you have some code `const objectA = {name: "myname"}` and `const objectB = {name: "myname"}` though those objects contain the same info they are not the same object so `objectA === objectB` is false meaning they are not referentially equal because they do not refer to the same object. However if you have `const objectA = {name: "myname"}` and `const objectB = objectA` then `objectA === objectB` is true and `objectA === objectB` is true even after doing something like `objectA.name = "oops"`

Answer (score -1):

best use the useState hook and to change the state just use the setState example:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState ("")
<input value = {inputValue} onChange = {(e) => setInputValue (e.target.value)} />
```